# How prove that $\int_2^{\infty}\left|\frac{\cos\sqrt{x}}{x^{\alpha}\ln x}\right|dx$ diverges with $\frac{1}{2}\leq \alpha \leq 1$

Tags: convergence-divergence

How would one prove that $\int_2^{\infty}\left|\frac{\cos\sqrt{x}}{x^{\alpha}\ln x}\right|dx$ diverges with $\frac{1}{2}\leq \alpha \leq 1$?

It converges for $\alpha > 1$ as $\int_2^{\infty}\left|\frac{\cos\sqrt{x}}{x^{\alpha}\ln x}\right|dx \leq \int_2^{\infty}\left|\frac{1}{x^{\alpha}\ln x}\right|dx$.

Comment: Better to typeset cos as $\text {\cos }$; same with ln.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio second, sorry

Answer (score 1):

With the change of variable $x=t^2$ the given integral becomes

$$ I(\alpha)=\int_{\sqrt{2}}^{+\infty}\frac{\left|\cos t\right|}{t^{2\alpha-1}\log t}\,dt $$
and the non-negative function $f(t)=\left|\cos t\right|$ has mean value $\frac{2}{\pi}$, hence by integration by parts the previous integral is convergent iff
$$ J(\alpha)=\frac{2}{\pi}\int_{\sqrt{2}}^{+\infty}\frac{dt}{t^{2\alpha-1}\log t} \stackrel{t\mapsto e^u}{=} \frac{2}{\pi}\int_{\frac{1}{2}\log 2}^{+\infty}e^{(2-2\alpha)u}\frac{du}{u} $$
is convergent, i.e. iff $\color{red}{\alpha > 1}$.

Comment: Explain please how integrate this by parts? @Jack D'Aurizio

Comment: @EugeneKorotkov: the usual way: integrate $\left|\cos t\right|$ and differentiate $\frac{1}{t^{2\alpha-1}\log t}$.